# while loop doesnt stop even after condition has been fulfilled

Tags: javascript, arrays, while-loop

***Functionality:***

User is to input the color based on a guessing game. Prompt will keep prompt when the answer is wrong, prompt will only exit when the user set the correct answer.

***WHat I have done:***
Have made use of a while loop to check the condition. In while loop, have set the while loop to finish only when it is equivalent to target, and target is a randomly picked color by the system

***Issue:***
Prompt initially set the color as the answer but prompt kept looping even after user has set the correct answer.

How to exit loop when one of the color is set?

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Color Guessing Game</title>
</head>

<body onload="do_game()">
  <script>
    function do_game() {
        var color = ["blue", "cyan", "gray", "green", "magenta", "orange", "red", "white", "yellow"];
        var guess_input_text, guess_input, finished = false,
          target, guesses = 0;

        var target_index = color[0, 8];
        target = target_index;
        alert(target);
        while (!finished) {
          guess_input_text = prompt("I am thinking of these colors:" +
            "\n\n blue, cyan, gray, green, magenta, orange, red, white, yellow" + "\n\n what color am I thinking of?");
          guess_input = parseInt(guess_input_text);
          guesses += 1;
          finished = target;
        }
      }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You never modify `finished` variable.

Comment: you need to set finished = true at some point of time to break out of the loop. Why is ur line "finished = check_guess();" commented? you need to add your conditions in that function and return boolean

Comment: you should first implement  check_guess function  then only we can help you.

Comment: @zerkms updated the question

Comment: @SwarnenduPaul updated the question

Comment: @premkumar updated the question

Comment: Setting `finished = target;` doesn't help much, you never change the `target` variable inside the loop ?

Comment: At some point `finished` has to be true so the loop stops. You're not changing `finished`, nor are you changing `target` inside the loop, so how is it going to change ?

Comment: @adeno, target is randomly set/ picked by the system so that means, finished is based on the system pick of the color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code which controls every round of the loop if the input is the same as the target and if they're the same then finished gets true:

```
function do_game() {
    var color = ["blue", "cyan", "gray", "green", "magenta", "orange", "red", "white", "yellow"];
    var guess_input_text, guess_input, finished = false,
      target, guesses = 0;

    var rnd = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9) + 0); //Makes a random number between 0 and 8
    target = color[rnd]; //sets the target to a random color from the color array
    while (!finished) {
      guess_input_text = prompt("I am thinking of these colors:" +
        "\n\n blue, cyan, gray, green, magenta, orange, red, white, yellow" + "\n\n what color am I thinking of?"); //gets alert-input from user
      guesses += 1;
      if(guess_input_text == target){//checks if input from user and target are the same
        finished = true;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: the loop is still forever looping, even after the correct answer has been inputted

Comment: Wait i will make a jsfiddle to check.

Comment: I hope it works but I couldn't test it because my browser won't alert.

Comment: this should work. ealier target = color[0,8] which evaluated to target="yellow". but while comparing target was compared with int

Comment: thanks!!!I am wondering why am I not able to set the following as `var target_index = color[0, 8];
        target = target_index;`??

Comment: so does that mean, that is always selecting yellow as the color?? but it doesn't explain why the loop will always be looping even if I have set the answer as yellow

Comment: @Luke target="yellow" but guess_input = parseInt(guess_input_text); . here guess_input is an integer because of parseInt. what is the user entering "yellow" or 8 or 9. 8 or 9 because for the user what is the index value starting from

Comment: @premkumar, understood, hence to allow random selection is to use:`Math.floor((Math.random() * 9) + 0); `, such that the integer value of the array can be randomly selected? but why is it that for the previous way that I have set; which is wrong, couldnt set the while loop to exit when condition is set, meaning, loop is still looping even when I have typed yellow??

Comment: @Luke because of parseInt. remove that and it should work fine

Comment: @Luke I have run your code snippet and for me it always finished even when I typed the wrong answer(AFTER YOUR EDIT)

Comment: @Orell??really?? I have managed to get the correct output working already

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing it without finished variable. Using break

```
var target_text = color[0, 8];
...
while (true) {
      guess_input_text = prompt("I am thinking of these colors:" +
        "\n\n blue, cyan, gray, green, magenta, orange, red, white, yellow" + "\n\n what color am I thinking of?");

      guesses += 1;
      if(guess_input_text == target_text){
       //guessed correct answer
       break;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't do what you think it does.

This doesn't get the index of a random value, it gets the last value.

```
var target_index = color[0,8];
```

This will get a random array value:
    var rand = color[Math.floor(Math.random() * color.length)];

Once you have the winning value, there's no point in doing an index comparison. You can simply compare strings, as prompt() returns the string of the input response (modified prompt text for brevity).

```
var finished = false;
while (!finished)
{
    var input = prompt("What color am I thinking of?");
    finished = (input.toLowerCase() === rand);
}
```